# How to handle onclick event in the Fusion chart's Org chart Visualization

Tags: javascript, event-handling, fusioncharts

I have tried with `entityClick` and `markerClick`([codepen link](https://codepen.io/NaveenDA/pen/eYNQmBW?editors=0010)), but it doesn't trigger. I could not find any information related to the organization chart in the [official documentation](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/events/classifying-events)

Comment: Use dataPlotClick event to trigger an event when the plot is clicked, here is a demo - https://codepen.io/ayan-bhadury/pen/YzXRVjq?editors=0010

Comment: Yeah thanks, please post as the answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs, you can able listen to the click events for any fusion charts plots by using `dataPlotClick()`.

Refer: [documentation](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events)